# How am I intended to use handler and dataProvider in swaggerize-express?

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I've written my first Swagger-spec and generated a server-stub using [generator-swagger](https://github.com/krakenjs/generator-swaggerize) ([swagerize-express](https://github.com/krakenjs/swaggerize-express)). For each path I get one handler and one dataProvider. **My question is how am I intended to use these?**

For a concrete question: **How would I change the following code so that I look for a user in the DB and return `200` if found or `404` if not found?**

The generated code for the handler:

```
 get: function getUser(req, res, next) {
        /**
         * Get the data for response 200
         */
        var status = 200;
        var provider = dataProvider['get']['200'];
        provider(req, res, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
                return;
            }
            res.status(status).send(data && data.responses);
        });
    }
```

The generated code for the dataProvider:

```
get: {
    200: function (req, res, callback) {
        /**
         * Using mock data generator module.
         * Replace this by actual data for the api.
         */
        Mockgen().responses({
            path: '/users/{id}',
            operation: 'get',
            response: '200'
        }, callback);
    },
    404: function (req, res, callback) {
        /**
         * Using mock data generator module.
         * Replace this by actual data for the api.
         */
        Mockgen().responses({
            path: '/users/{id}',
            operation: 'get',
            response: '404'
        }, callback);
    }
}
```

**I know I could make the DB look-up in the handler. But isn't that the purpose of the dataProvider?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to share how I decided to structure my application. However, I'd love to hear if you found a more effective way to do so. Here are the basic concepts I had in mind:

- handler - Should manage all route related logic, meaning parameter and attribute validation and routing to the correct dataProvider
- dataProvider - Should manage interactions with the model layer / database. Passing control back to the handler if it is ultimately not the correct dataProvider.

**handler/user/{id}.js**

```
get: function getUser(req, res, next) {
  var status = 200;
  var provider = dataProvider['get']['200'];

  // Check if params.id is a valid integer
  // If not, get response from dataProvider['get']['400']
  if (isNaN(req.params.id)) {
    status = 400;
    provider = dataProvider['get']['400'];
    provider(req, res, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.status(status).send(data && data.responses)
    });
    return;
  }

  provider(req, res, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    // Check if user with id exists
    // If not, get response from dataProvider['get']['404']
    if (!data) {
      status = 404;
      provider = dataProvider['get']['404'];
      provider(req, res, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        res.status(status).send(data && data.responses)
      });
      return;
    }
    res.status(status).send(data && data.responses);
  });
}
```

**data/user/{id}.js**

```
get: {
  200: function(req, res, callback) {
    User.find({
      where: {
        id: req.params.id
      }
    }).then(function(object) {
      if (!object) {
        return callback(null, null);
      }
      callback(null, {
        responses: object.toJSON()
      });
    });
  },
  400: function(req, res, callback) {
    callback(null, {
      responses: ERR.USER.INVALIDID
    });
  },
  404: function(req, res, callback) {
    callback(null, {
      responses: ERR.USER.NOTFOUND
    });
  }
},
```

I think it looks like how it was designed to separate the responsibilities nicely. I'm not sure if this pattern is taken from another framework/language, but I couldn't find much online to support this. What do you think?

Comment: Actually I ended up doing it manually, instead of using swaggerize-express, to better comply with the existing system. But I think your answer is the best solution of the ones I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused as well. Did you find the solution? I found out that I can use the provided `callback` to send a response in the positive case (i.e. when the data base item is found).

```
var id = req.params.id;
// item = ... get your data base item via id ...
callback(null, { responses: item });
```

I'm still wondering though which parameters to pass to `callback` in the negative case. I tried to call `callback(404)` indicating that I want the server to give a "Resource Not Found" response. This, however, results in a HTTP-500 Error.

Comment: No unfortunately I still haven't found a solution.